# jQuery: Freezing/Disabling all events temporarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following usecase:

- A div with some buttons
- When the user
  clicks on a button, a popup is shown
  and the background div is faded out
  to 0.5 opacity

The problem is that when the popup comes in, the user is still able to click on the background buttons. At this point, I can remove the entire DIV temporarily but I don't want to do that. Is there anyway I can disable all the previously attached events and then add event handlers ONLY to the current popup? (I mean something like a close button should still work on a popup) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [**modal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) popup.  There are numerous jQuery plugins that do that, or you can check out [this tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

You could store each element with an attached event into an array, then loop through them and `unbind()` them. Upon closing the popup you can re-`bind()` them.

Comment: +1 for this. I tried this approach but somehow thought it could end up being heavy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modal dialog option built into JQuery UI

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

```
$("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                   modal: true
                   });
```